# Unable to keep a peristent login with the oauth2orize provider using ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm working on creating an app that will provide authentication using the OAuth2 protocol to serve known clients using the app's Strategy.

I have tried using both the `oauth2orize`, and `node-oauth2-provider` modules, and I keep getting the to same point:

1. User logs in through client, *api key* and *api secret* are verified, and the user can successfully log in through my provider app.
2. After the client app, and the user successfully authenticate, a token is sent back to the client app (user is logged in the client - yay!), but the user is immediately logged out on the `Provider` app. I cannot figure out where, and why this happens - is this a feature of the OAuth2 protocol?

Is this normal? If I use Facebook as a strategy (think `passport-facebook`), then if I log in to any app using Facebook, I am still logged into Facebook when I'm redirected back to the app - **this** is the behavior I want to provide clients accessing my app.

Both Provider modules are great at doing 90% of what I'm looking for, but neither provide the "persistent" login in their examples, [oauth2orize](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize/tree/master/examples/express2), and [node-oauth2-provider](https://github.com/ammmir/node-oauth2-provider/tree/master/examples). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7):

Um, I think I got it.

I was running both the client and server on `localhost`, using different ports - and cookies/sessions were overwriting each other.

So if client express app was running on `http://localhost:3000` and oauth provider was running on `http://localhost:3001`, logging into the oauth provider and creating a session on the client was overwriting the session on the provider.

Solution (for now):

```
# /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 dev.client.com
127.0.0.1 dev.oauth-provider.com
```

Logging in to http://dev.client.com:3000 takes me to http://dev.oauth-provider.com:3001 and when a user successfully logs in and a session is created on client, provider is still logged in.

Comment: thanks Johnny! you saved hours of scratching my head :)

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you for this. (sorry for the "thank you" kind of comment...but this is well deserved)